# How do i add filtering to the dictionary

Tags: json, list, dictionary, ansible

I am trying to query the list from a dictionary which ends with digit 1.

This is what i am trying, but i am getting empty list as output.

```
    - name: Get list of sid that are open in READ WRITE mode
      set_fact:
        sid_output: "{{ om.results | selectattr(\"sid\", \"match\", \"1$\") | map(attribute='sid') | list}}"
```

Here is the output from my dictionary:

```
{
   'msg':u'All items completed',
   'changed':True,
   'results':[  
      {  
         '_ansible_parsed':True,
         'stderr_lines':[  

         ],
         u'cmd':u'echo \"set pagesize 0\\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\\\$database;\" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba',
         u'end':         u'2019-05-15 12:04:30.478084         ', '         _ansible_no_log':False,
         u'stdout':u'READ WRITE',
         '_ansible_item_result':True,
         u'changed':True,
         u'sid':u'dw1',
         'failed':False,
         u'delta':         u'0:00:00.073102         ', u'         stderr':u'',
         u'rc':0,
         u'invocation':{  
            u'module_args':{  
               u'creates':None,
               u'executable':None,
               u'_uses_shell':True,
               u'_raw_params':u'echo \"set pagesize 0\\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\\\$database;\" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba',
               u'removes':None,
               u'argv':None,
               u'warn':True,
               u'chdir':None,
               u'stdin':None
            }
         },
         'stdout_lines':[  
            u'READ WRITE'
         ],
         u'start':         u'2019-05-15 12:04:30.404982         ', '         _ansible_ignore_errors':None,
         '_ansible_item_label':u'dw1'
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This is the output i am seeing if i use the above filtering:

TASK [Get list of sid that are open in READ WRITE mode] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /uhome/ansible/sql_script_execute.yaml:44
ok: [dwracdb1.com] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "sid_output": []
    },
    "changed": false
}

Comment: If you have new information to add to your question, please **update the question** rather than posting it in a comment. It is not possible to properly format things in comments, which makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the use of the `match` test. From the [documentation on search vs. match](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings):

> ‘match’ requires a complete match in the string, while ‘search’ only requires matching a subset of the string.

In other words, if you try to test using `some_match is match('foo.*bar')`, that means that the string must start with `foo` and end with `bar`.  If you test `some_mastch is match('bar$')`, then you're looking for strings that are *exactly equal* to `bar`.

Since you're using:

```
selectattr(\"sid\", \"match\", \"1$\")
```

This means it will only match strings that exactly equal `1`.  You want to use `search` instead. And while you're at it, get rid of all those escaped double-quotes:

```
- set_fact:
    sid_output: "{{ om.results | selectattr('sid', 'search', '1$') | map(attribute='sid') | list}}"
```

With your example data, this will set `sid_output` to `dw1`.